# Nested json object into certain format in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tsx

I am working on it on react app with typescript.
I have a complex nested Json object that should be formatted into certain format.

```
const a = {
    "aaa": {
        "aa": {
            "xxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            }
        },
        "ab": {
            "xxx": {},
            "xxxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            },
            "yyy": {
                "yyyy": {},
                "zzzz": {},
                "kkkk": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "bbb": {
        "": {}
    }
}
```

To do it, I made the code below.

```
function showJson(obj: any, label: number) {
        let returnValue = '';
        if (label === 0)
            returnValue += '['
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                returnValue += '{"value":' + label + ',';
                returnValue += '"label":"' + key + '",';
                returnValue += '"child":[' + showJson(obj[key], label + 1) + '],';
            } else {
                returnValue += '"value":' + label + ',"label":' + key + '"child":{' + obj[key] + '}}]';
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

then I will parse this through Json.parse().
However, this doesn't well formatting the data..
I can't close curly braces properly and it complains 'key is duplicated.'
Would anybody could help me fix it?

```
[
  {
    "value": "aaa",
    "label": "aaa",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "aa",
        "label": "aa",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "xxx",
            "label": "xxx",
            "children": [
              {
                "value": "xxxx",
                "label": "xxxx"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "ab",
        "label": "ab",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "xxx",
            "label": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "value": "xxxx",
            "label": "xxxx",
            "children": [
              {
                "value": "xxxx",
                "label": "xxxx"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": "yyy",
            "label": "yyy",
            "children": [
              {
                "value": "yyyy",
                "label": "yyyy"
              },
              {
                "value": "zzzz",
                "label": "zzzz"
              },
              {
                "value": "kkkk",
                "label": "kkkk"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "bbb",
    "label": "bbb",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "",
        "label": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Instead of trying to create JSON manually, you should try to create and populate the corresponding data object. If you still need the result in JSON format afterwards, then you can encode your object as JSON then.

Comment: Why do you want to create JSON when in the end you need to parse it? Just create the object structure directly.

Comment: why `value` and `label` if they're always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be necessary to build JSON by string manipulation. Moreover, as you seem interested in the actual data structure -- since you want to call `JSON.parse()` on it -- there shouldn't be any need of JSON. Instead focus on building the data structure directly.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
function transform(data) {
    return Object.entries(data).map(([label, data]) => {
        const children = transform(data);
        return { value: label, label, ...children.length && {children} }
    });
}

// Example from the question
const a = {"aaa": {"aa": {"xxx": {"xxxx": {}}},"ab": {"xxx": {},"xxxx": {"xxxx": {}},"yyy": {"yyyy": {},"zzzz": {},"kkkk": {}}}},"bbb": {"": {}}}

console.log(transform(a));
```

If ever you would need the JSON equivalent of that resulting data structure, then call `JSON.stringify` on it.

Comment: brilliant!! it's simple and elegant solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know how to not making value's value not duplicated? I am doing this for using the object in CheckboxTree nodes, and it error 'all node values must be unique'

Comment: Generally you make a list of values unique by collecting them in an array, and turn it into a set. This should be done before even building a tree structure. If you cannot make it work, then please consider posting a new question about that.